# How do I get Apache POI and JAXB to work together?

Tags: java, intellij-idea, jaxb, apache-poi, xmlbeans

```
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.xmlbeans.XmlObject
```

I get that error when I run my code. Ok, that's fine - I just forgot to get XMLBeans... but it's been retired and I can't find a recent version in their archives. So I found that JAXB can be an alternative, I downloaded it and tried adding the jar files to my library in Intellij, but I still get the same error looking for the XMLBeans dependency.

How do I get Apache POI to use JAXB in place of XMLBeans? Why does JAXB have like 7 different jar files and I can't find out what any of them do? I just want to work on some excel files and not go on a wild goose chase :(

Answer (score 3, accepted):

XMLBeans is a dependency of Apache POI and POI won't use a different library in it's place. XMLBeans comes packaged in the Apache POI downloads which I have checked, so you should have it available to you. You just need to ensure the xmlbeans jar file is in the java classpath when running your application.

I have checked the latest POI binary tar.gz file 'poi-bin-3.14.tar.gz' available from http://poi.apache.org/download.html#POI-3.14, extracting the compressed tar archive (I use 7-Zip), you will find xmlbeans-2.6.0.jar in the poi-3.14/ooxml-lib directory.

Comment: Although, I have to answer the question, 'How do I get Apache POI and JAXB to work together?'. The plain answer, if you really want to do this, you actually need to get the entire source code for Apache POI, modify this and change all references to XMLBeans classes to corresponding JAXB classes if there are usable classes. You would also need to fill in the gaps by writing your own classes where there may not be a class available to serve a specific need for your version of POI to compile and be functional for your needs. This isn't really a trivial task.

Comment: I can't believe the damn jar was there the whole time ugh I'm dumb. Thank you for the fast response, I really appreciate it. By chance do you happen to know why the Apache POI documentation isn't working when I link it in Intellij?