# Trouble with Apache POI excel export

Tags: java, excel, apache-poi

I am trying to use `Apache POI` to export a `SQLite` database into an .xlsx or a xls. It seems to have no trouble getting to the table but right after that `XSSFWorkbook workbook = new XSSFWorkbook();` throws an error. It does suggest that I close `workbook` but that does not solve my problem..

**My Code:**

```
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.DriverManager;
import java.sql.ResultSet;
import java.sql.Statement;
import java.sql.SQLException;
import org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFCell;
import org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFRow;
import org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFSheet;
import org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFWorkbook;
public class Export 
{

public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception 
{

    Connection connection = null;
    //@Override
    //public Connection getConection() throws SQLException {


        try {
            Class.forName("org.sqlite.JDBC");


             connection = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:sqlite:" +"C:/Test/DATABASE.db");  
            throw new SQLException(e.getMessage());
        } catch (Exception e) {
            throw new SQLException(e.getCause());
        }

DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:sqlite:" + "resources\\COPY_TRACARGODB.db");
  Statement statement = connection.createStatement();
  ResultSet resultSet = statement
  .executeQuery("select * from BILL_LADING");
  XSSFWorkbook workbook = new XSSFWorkbook(); 
  XSSFSheet spreadsheet = workbook
  .createSheet("Tracargo EXPORTED DB");
  XSSFRow row=spreadsheet.createRow(1);
  XSSFCell cell;
  cell=row.createCell(1);
  cell.setCellValue("First Name");
  cell=row.createCell(2);
  cell.setCellValue("Last Name");
  cell=row.createCell(3);
  cell.setCellValue("Date");
  cell=row.createCell(4);
  cell.setCellValue("Time");
  cell=row.createCell(5);
  cell.setCellValue("Destination");
  int i=2;
  while(resultSet.next())
  {
     row=spreadsheet.createRow(i);
     cell=row.createCell(1);
     cell.setCellValue(resultSet.getInt("first_name"));
     cell=row.createCell(2);
     cell.setCellValue(resultSet.getString("last_name"));
     cell=row.createCell(3);
     cell.setCellValue(resultSet.getString("date"));
     cell=row.createCell(4);
     cell.setCellValue(resultSet.getString("time"));
     cell=row.createCell(5);
     cell.setCellValue(resultSet.getString("destination"));
     i++;
  }
  FileOutputStream out = new FileOutputStream(
  new File("exceldatabase.xlsx"));
  workbook.write(out);
  out.close();
 // workbook.close();
  System.out.println(
  "exceldatabase.xlsx written successfully");
}
}
```

**My Errors:**

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/xmlbeans/XmlObject
at Export.main(Export.java:38)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.xmlbeans.XmlObject
at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
... 1 more
```

Comment: `ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.xmlbeans.XmlObject` --The Apache XMLBeans jar file is missing in your deployed environment.

Comment: As @JimGarrison points out, you need to have xmlbeans (and the other lib dependencies poi-ooxml) in your classpath when running your program. Another stackoverflower had this problem lately here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38042811/how-do-i-get-apache-poi-and-jaxb-to-work-together/38042999#38042999

Comment: Thanks guys! I appreciate it!